# Dynamic Where Clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to build a dynamic where clause in a stored procedure such that if the parameter is empty, you select all item in the table?  However, if you do have a parameter, you select items where the condition is true?

Comment: `WHERE (@parameter IS NULL OR col = @parameter)`

Comment: You can do it dynamically or with a simple `where` clause:  `where (@id is null or id = @id)`.

Comment: if i have a procedure called test and I want to select all,  would I do call test(null)?

Comment: if i do call test(), it would say incorrect number of arguments

Answer (score 2):

Here is the trick... you can create a string query 
for your select command, and then manipulate it by conditional statement.. see sample below.. hope you can apply the logic on your work.

```
    -- Put a default value `NULL` to your parameter first
    CREATE TABLE TableNameHere 
    (
      @ParameterName VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    )

    DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

    --Initialize SQL statement first
    --It will return true always , therefor it will display all data
    SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM TableNameHere WHERE 1 = 1' 

    -- If parameter has a value then do the where condition inside the block
    IF @ParameterName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
           SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND ColumnNameHere = ''' + @ParameterName + ''''
        END

    EXEC(@SQLQuery)
```